# Возможно ли инвертировать детектинг файлов в GIT?

Tags: git, gitignore

Для того что бы файлы не попадали в обработку их нужно занести в **gitignore** файл. А можно ли сделать наоборот, то есть например указать что надо обработать такой то файл, а остальные не брать в учет.

Comment: Получается "оборонительный контроль версий", по аналогии с defensive programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В `.gitignore` можно инвертировать правила с помощью `!`:

```
*
!*.html
```

Теперь git будет игнорировать все файлы, кроме тех, что попадают под паттерн `*.html`.

Документация [`.gitignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

Answer (score 5):

<s>Можно просто не пользоваться командами наподобие `git add .` и добавлять файлы только по-одному.</s>

Еще можно написать в `.gitignore` * (т.е. все файлы), а добавлять их по-одному через `git add -f`

Не забывайте, что файл, который уже есть в репозитории, будет отслеживаться независимо от того что написано в `.gitignore`

Comment: тогда вручную придется просматривать список изменений и есть шанс допустить ошибку.

Comment: @perfect да, точно. Значит, первый вариант снимается. Хотя список изменений лично я всегда просматриваю вручную.

Comment: а форсированное добавление сработает с пустым списком изменений?

Comment: @perfect А почему нет?

Comment: просто не знаю чем руководствуется **force** режим

Comment: @perfect Читайте [документацию](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). `force` в данном случае не означает ничего кроме игнорирования файла `.gitignore`

Comment: спасибо за дополнение